# How to getting input checked in a form, if other form has input with the same value?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

Hey guys I have two forms

First Form has 3 Radio inputs [Nike, meow,yamomo]

Second Form has 3 checkboxes [Nike, meow,yamomo]

I want when I click one of the Checkboxes like Nike, I want the input with same name in another form get checked too

**HTML**

```
<form id="first_form">
    <ul class="widget-menu-sobex-input-list">

        <li>
            <label class="input-container">
            <input type="radio" value="1" name="brand" />
            <span>Nike</span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="input-container">
            <input type="radio" value="2" name="brand" />
            <span>meow</span>
            </label>
        </li>
                                 
        <li>
            <label class="input-container">
            <input type="radio" value="3" name="brand" />
            <span>yamomo</span>
            </label>
        </li>
                            
    </ul>
</form>
```

**Second Form**

```
<form id="second_form">
    <label class="input-container">
      <span>nike</span>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="brand[]"/>
    </label>
    <label class="input-container">
      <span>meow</span>
      <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="brand[]"/>
    </label>
   
    <label class="input-container">
      <span>yamomo</span>
      <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="brand[]"/>
    </label>
</form>
```

Comment: Is this 2 forms on the same page?

Comment: What if the user marks _two_ of the checkboxes? You can not have more than one of the radio buttons checked simultaneously.

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes on the same page, I have tried a lot to find but the codes are wrong so no matter to share it here.

Comment: @CBroe I didn't notice that thanks but let's say both of them are checkboxes?

Comment: _I have tried a lot to find but the codes_ You do find code, you write it!

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty easy to do using jQuery.

Bind a change handler to the checkbox input fields in the second form, and then select the checkbox input with the corresponding value from the first form, and set it's `checked` property to the same as that of the checkbox in the second form.

```js
$('#second_form input[type=checkbox]').on('change', function() {
  $('#first_form input[type=checkbox][value='+$(this).val()+']').prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
First Form
<form id="first_form">
    <ul class="widget-menu-sobex-input-list">

        <li>
            <label class="input-container">
            <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="brand" />
            <span>Nike</span>
            </label>
        </li>
        <li>
            <label class="input-container">
            <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="brand" />
            <span>meow</span>
            </label>
        </li>
                                 
        <li>
            <label class="input-container">
            <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="brand" />
            <span>yamomo</span>
            </label>
        </li>
                            
    </ul>
</form>
Second Form

<form id="second_form">
    <label class="input-container">
      <span>nike</span>
      <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="brand[]"/>
    </label>
    <label class="input-container">
      <span>meow</span>
      <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="brand[]"/>
    </label>
   
    <label class="input-container">
      <span>yamomo</span>
      <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="brand[]"/>
    </label>
</form>
```